# Rails server hanging even with even freshly created app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

My rails server started hanging today, so I tried running different apps to see if the issue was caused by my app, even created an empty app and with that even the default page doesn't come up.

I've been using it as just an http server, testing front-end with adding files into the public folder, so, I don't even compile any actual ruby code, just plain HTML, CSS and JS.

When I try to browse localhost:3000, the page is unresponsive, I can't even view source and I'd like to add that this happens with Chrome, Safari, IE and Edge, so I don't think it's a caching issue on the browser front.

I tried running the server on a specific ip and port, also tried the 0.0.0.0 trick mentioned on some other questions, doesn't help me so far.

I'm using ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15] and Rails 4.2.5.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to look at your log to see what happens when you request a page.

Comment: Hi @Sharj, thanks for your interest. Nothing comes up on the log, the server acts like nothing was requested. It stays as if I started the server and did nothing else.

Comment: What happens when you try 'rails c', which webserver do you use ? Can you show us the terminal output ?

Comment: How did you install Ruby?

Comment: @NejatCanÜnlü If I remember once I had the same problem with I suspected the server i.e `webrick` to be the culprit upgraded the server to `thin` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up resolving the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling the whole stack. Couldn't find the reason behind the issue but if you get stuck with the same problem, apparently a complete reinstall fixes it...